# how to return the class of an element in xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

So I am successfully getting back some data with xpath about days of the month but I want to get the class of that column. For instance some days have the class "free" or "booked". How can I retrieve this in xpath?

```
year1.append(tree.xpath('//*[@id="inhalt_fewo"]/div[15]/table[1]/tr['+month+']/td/text()'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `@class` instead of `text()`:

```
/*[@id="inhalt_fewo"]/div[15]/table[1]/tr['+month+']/td/@class
```

Or, you may locate the element first and then use the [`.attrib`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#attrib) property:

```
elm = tree.xpath('//*[@id="inhalt_fewo"]/div[15]/table[1]/tr['+month+']/td')[0]

print(elm.text_content())
print(elm.attrib.get("class"))
```